# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem using the command line `dotnet ef database update`. Before it I call migrations with `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -o Data/Migrations` and it works.

storeContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using API.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace API.Data
{
        public class StoreContext : DbContext
    {
        public StoreContext(DbContextOptions<StoreContext> options) : base(options)  
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

}
```

StoreContextFactory.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace API.Data
{
    public class StoreContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<StoreContext>
    {
        public StoreContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
         var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StoreContext>();
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("DefaultConnection");

         return new StoreContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

program.cs

```
using API.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(opt =>
{
    //opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
    opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
}
);
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data source=store.db"
  }
}
```

The error:

```
dotnet ef database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.GetPoolGroup(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalLoggerExtensions.MigrateUsingConnection(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, IMigrator migrator, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```